# Подключение к голосовому каналу discord py. ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть музыкальный бот. Я столкнулся я проблемой в подключении бота к голосовому каналу: Если бот отключается сам(`await self.connection.disconnect()`), то всё хорошо, но если его выгоняет админ(кнопкой 'отключить'), то `self.connection` понимает, что его отключили и при вызове `self.connection.is_connected()` выдаёт `False`, а `self.voice_channel` при попытке подключится заново выдаёт `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel`. Как это можно исправить и правильно ли я вообще подключаюсь? Вот часть кода:

```
async def get_connect(self, ctx) -> None:
    if self.connect is None or not self.connect.is_connected():
        self.voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=ctx.message.author.voice.channel.name)
        self.connect = await self.voice_channel.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Это условие:

```
if self.connect is None or not self.connect.is_connected():
```

заменить на:

```
if self.voice_channel == None or not self.voice_channel.is_connected():
```